# TypeError: x is not a function in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, node-modules

I'm developing an Electron application and I aim to 'split up' `index.js` (main process) file. Currently I have put my menu bar-related and Touch Bar-related code into two separate files, `menu.js` and `touchBar.js`. Both of these files rely on a function named `redir`, which is in `index.js`. Whenever I attempt to activate the `click` event in my Menu Bar - which relies on `redir` - I get an error:

`TypeError: redir is not a function`. This also applies to my Touch Bar code.

Here are my (truncated) files:

`index.js`

```
const { app, BrowserWindow } = require('electron'); // eslint-disable-line
const initTB = require('./touchBar.js');
const initMenu = require('./menu.js');

...

let mainWindow; // eslint-disable-line

// Routing + IPC
const redir = (route) => {
  if (mainWindow.webContents) {
    mainWindow.webContents.send('redir', route);
  }
};
module.exports.redir = redir;

function createWindow() {
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    height: 600,
    width: 800,
    title: 'Braindead',
    titleBarStyle: 'hiddenInset',
    show: false,
    resizable: false,
    maximizable: false,
  });

  mainWindow.loadURL(winURL);
  initMenu();
  mainWindow.setTouchBar(initTB);

  ...

}

app.on('ready', createWindow);

...
```

`menu.js`

```
const redir = require('./index');
const { app, Menu, shell } = require('electron'); // eslint-disable-line

// Generate template
function getMenuTemplate() {
  const template = [

    ...

    {
      label: 'Help',
      role: 'help',
      submenu: [
        {
          label: 'Learn more about x',
          click: () => {
            shell.openExternal('x'); // these DO work.
          },
        },

        ...

      ],
    },
  ];

  if (process.platform === 'darwin') {
    template.unshift({
      label: 'Braindead',
      submenu: [

        ...

        {
          label: 'Preferences...',
          accelerator: 'Cmd+,',
          click: () => {
            redir('/preferences'); // this does NOT work
          },
        } 

        ...

      ],
    });

    ...

  };

  return template;
}

// Set the menu
module.exports = function initMenu() {
  const menu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(getMenuTemplate());
  Menu.setApplicationMenu(menu);
};
```

My file structure is simple - all three files are in the same directory.

Any code criticisms are also welcome; I've spent hours banging my head trying to figure all this out.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`redir` it is not a function, because you're exporting an object, containing a `redir` property, which is a function.

So you should either use:

```
const { redir } = require('./index.js');
```

Or export it this way

```
module.exports = redir
```

When you do: `module.exports.redir = redir;`

You're exporting: `{ redir: [Function] }`

Answer (score 4):

You are exporting

```
module.exports.redir = redir;
```

That means that your import

```
const redir = require('./index');
```

is the exported object. `redir` happens to be one of its keys. To use the function, use

```
const redir = require('./index').redir;
```

or destructure directly into redir

```
const { redir } = require('./index');
```